# Text classification- What to do when train and test data have different features

Tags: r, machine-learning, text-mining, text-classification

I am performing binary text classification. I have to classify a tweet 0 if neutral and 1 if hate speech.

So as general thumb rule i preprocessed my data. create term document frequency and After removing sparse terms i divide my data into train and test. 
I train my model using random forest and logistic regression and it worked fine.

```
set.seed(123)
tweetRand = randomForest(label ~ ., data = train_sparse, importance=TRUE, nTree=500 )
randPridct = predict(tweetRand, newdata = test_sparse)
table(test_sparse$label,randPridct >=0.5)
```

Its is working fine on test data which divided from raw content. 
But when i am running it on a new unseen data it is throwing an exception.

```
> predicrRand_test=predict(tweetRand, newdata=sparse_4testing)
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'run' not found
```

My understanding is that 'run' is a feature present in training but not in unseen test data and during my model training 'run' was included in tdm. 
In preprocessing of test , run was not in test tdm.

SO how should i deal with these situation. I am new to data science. Please help.

Comment: you may need to retrain with the features present in the test to avoid the error i.e. using `?intersect` to find the common features and then train/test.  I think the `randomForest` would also have problems if there is additional levels

Comment: sorry for the confusion. 'run' feature is present in training tdm matrix but not in unseen data's tdm matrix

Comment: in both cases, it would fail

Comment: any workaround or can you please suggest some other algorithm. I mean its not practice to retrain the model if a new tweet have some new term appears or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of situations, usually the best approach is to ignore the new features (tokens) in your live test data.

You can achieve this by:

- Building your training vocabulary (create a set of all the features/tokens used in your training set).
- Filter all your new test instances, removing all tokens/feature that are not included in your training vocabulary.